# Update java object's properties by another object of same type

Tags: java, arraylist

can you give me example how to update values in one object by another object of same type? For example here is my class:

```
public class MyObj {
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String phone;
   private String address;

   // some getters and settters ...
}
```

And I have another class with that stuff:

```
private ArrayList<MyObj> objectsList; // list of some objects
public MyObj update ( MyObj newObj ) {

    // here I need set new values of properties of newObj to object with same id property in objectsList;
}
```

Exist some way how to do that without manually setting up all properties?

Comment: No, there isn't any clean way to do that. You'll need to write those 3 lines of code.

Comment: You could use reflection -- that's about it.

Comment: It might be cleaner to create a copy-constructor inside `MyObj` and use it whenever you need to create a dup. This approach also avoids potential concurrency issues which you might encounter while "updating" an object field-by-field, since now all you're doing is reference assignment which is an atomic operation.

Answer (score 2):

You have to identify the object in the list by iterating on it or replacing by a `Map<String, MyObj>`

> Exist some way how to do that without manually setting up all
>   properties?

Sure.
Reflection addresses it but reflection has a cost (it is slower) and it may fail at runtime or give a unexpected behavior.
You can do it manually or better use a library that does the task for you.
But in your case, to handle just 3 fields, it seems an overhead to use reflection.
Just use setters to set them :

```
MyObj existingObj = ...; // retrieved by a search
existingObj.setName(newObj.getName());
existingObj.setPhone(newObj.getPhone());
existingObj.setAddress(newObj.getAddress());
```

As alternative, if changing the reference of the object is not a concern, just replace the object actually in the list by which one provided in parameter :

```
int indexOfTheObject = ...;  // retrieved by a search
objectsList.set(indexOfTheObject, newObj);
```